# How to let users choose where to search for posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, search, meta-query

I have no code to let you correct/see, I'm still in 'thinking stage'. What i would like to achieve is this:
A real estate website with a few search functionalities.
This new agency (REALLY NEW we have no office actually!) will split the city in 4 (or more) parts, in each one of these part there will be different houses, each house will have different number of rooms or will be available only to girs/boys.

So the user when reach my website have to be able to choose:

Search Form 1

- Which Part of the city

  - Accept boy/girls/both
  - Budget

Search Form 2

- Accept boy/girls/both

  - Budget
  - Which part

And so on...
Maybe the best way to have a simpler search query would be to use Custom Field, Am I wrong?

Is there anyone who can help me to find a tutorial, or can point me to the right direction or has/know a plugin to do something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problems using this simple plugin: http://www.don-benjamin.co.uk/tag/custom-search/